# AnimationPresence not working — checked positioning and key props

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I'm using Framer Motion 7.3.6 together with NextJS 12.2.2 and trying to create a simple page transition.

First, I created a wrapper component as follows:

```
//PageWrapper.js
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const PageWrapper = ({ children }) => {

  return (
    <motion.div
      initial={{ opacity: 0, y: 20 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
      exit={{ opacity: 0, y: 20 }}
    >
      {children}
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default PageWrapper;
```

Then went ahead and updated my `app.js` file.

```
// app.js
import "../styles/global.css";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar/Navbar";
import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps, router }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
        <Component {...pageProps} key={router.route} />
      </AnimatePresence>
    </>
  );
}
```

And then wrapped my `index.js`in it.

```
Currently at//index.js
import styles from "./index.module.css";
import ShuffleText from "../components/shuffletext";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar/Navbar";
import Footer from "../components/Footer/Footer";
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion";
import PageWrapper from "../components/PageWrapper";

export default function Home() {
  const itemVariants = {
    hidden: { y: 30, opacity: 0 },
    visible: { y: 0, opacity: 1 },
  };

  return (
    <PageWrapper>
        <Navbar />
        <div className={styles.Wrapper}>
          <motion.div
            className={styles.mainContent}
            initial="hidden"
            animate="visible"
            key="mainContent"
          >
            <motion.p
              variants={itemVariants}
              initial="hidden"
              animate="visible"
              key="first"
              exit={{ y: -200, opacity: 0 }}
              transition={{ type: "spring", damping: 20, stiffness: 40 }}
            >
              First line
            </motion.p>
            <motion.p
              variants={itemVariants}
              initial="hidden"
              animate="visible"
              key="second"
              transition={{
                type: "spring",
                damping: 20,
                stiffness: 40,
                delay: 0.2,
              }}
              exit={{ y: -200, opacity: 0 }}
            >
              Second line
              </a>
            </motion.p>
          </motion.div>
        </div>
      <Footer />
    </PageWrapper>
      );
}
```

I get to see the animation when the page renders but not the exit animation. I've been trying to use `<AnimatePresence>` in others parts but without success as well.

I tried many many permutations of positioning, tried passing different keys, equal keys, no keys. Nothing seems to make this work.

One thing I believe could be related by have failed to test so far is I'm using `<a>` to navigate trough pages and not `<Link>` as I'm using a `<ShuffleText/>` component to create a result similar to this when users hover over links https://locomotive.ca/en. And I'm unable to do something like `<Link hrf="/"><ShuffleText text={"example"}/></Link>`.

Any ideas what could be causing this behavior? Is it related to not using `<Link>`?

EDIT: Adding a partial solution to the problem that I just tried. It's partial because it's working to go from `/writing'` to `/writing/[slug]` but not from `'/'` to `'/writing'`. At this point I'm pretty convinced it has something to do with `<Link/>` because to go to the `/[slug]` I'm using the NextJS component.

```
import "../styles/global.css";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar/Navbar";
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <>
      <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
        <motion.div
          key={router.route}
          initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
          animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
          exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
          transition={{
            duration: 1,
            ease: "easeInOut",
          }}
        >
          <Navbar />

          <Component {...pageProps} key={router.route} />
        </motion.div>
      </AnimatePresence>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't see PageWrapper being used anywhere from the code snippets you provided.

Comment: @khangnd, my bad I posted a version of the code where I tried to make it work without the `<PageWrapper/>`. I just updated it to the correct version, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to how `<AnimatePresence/>` detects (or not) if a component is being unmounted. Because I was not using `<Link/>` to navigate trough internal pages, Framer Motion was unable to detect the unmounting process. That being said all I had to do was replace `<a>` links for `<Link/>`.